# returned objects by read_csv in Pandas

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I am using `read_csv` method in Pandas to input multiple .csv files. I print out the objects returned by `read_csv`, and am curious about the differences in the output:

For example, one printout is:

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 10 entries, 0 to 9
Data columns (total 5 columns):
col_1           10  non-null values
col_2           10  non-null values
col_3           10  non-null values
col_4           10  non-null values
col_5           10  non-null values
dtypes: int64(5)
```

while another one is simply:

```
   col_a  col_b  col_c  col_d  col_e  col_f
0      1      1      1 183227      1 181913
1      2      1      1 183234      1 183003
...
```

How should I interpret the differences in these outputs? Why the second file does not result in a `DataFrame` object?

Comment: Pandas will truncate the output if the result is likely to exceed the default settings, you can change this using `set_option('display.max_rows', 1000)` or whatevery value, you can lookup the docstring and if you in IPython and perform a tab completion it will show you the default setting and the current settings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are both DataFrames.  If the output is longer than a few rows, Pandas displays the summary information in the first format so it won't fill up your screen.

If you want the full display, you can use the `.to_string()` method on the DataFrame.  That is, if `df`, is your DataFrame, you can do `print df.to_string()` to see all the data, even if it's long.

Answer (score 3):

In both cases, `read_csv` is returning a DataFrame. However, when you print a DataFrame, its `__str__` method is called, and this method may choose to represent the DataFrame differently depending on its dimensions (columns, rows and total width).

By default, Pandas displays at most 20 columns and 60 rows. If a DataFrame exceeds these dimensions, then it uses a summarized format, such as

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 10 entries, 0 to 9
Data columns (total 5 columns):
col_1           10  non-null values
col_2           10  non-null values
col_3           10  non-null values
col_4           10  non-null values
col_5           10  non-null values
dtypes: int64(5)
```

To display the full DataFrame, you can change the `display.max_columns`, `display.max_rows`, and `display.width` options:

```
import pandas as pd
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', 30)
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', 100)    
pd.set_option('display.width', 120)
```